# Windows 10 goes to login screen even though set not to

Tags: windows-10

I have all the settings under display and registry not to go to sleep, not to go to login screen, and also set in the group policies yet when I walk away from this PC and come back after hours it is back at the login screen.  I am still logged in but I have to put in a password to get back in.  I cannot have this as it is used by multiple people for a particular purpose and it needs to be at a visible screen/application all the time.  Why is it going back to login?  It's like the screen saver is kicking on even though I have it set to none and no login.  It worked fine for a couple years and is only now doing this.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was check the power plans because sometimes one of the options cause the issue that you face.

[image]

But...

You will laugh but I chose an absolute different way to solve this issue. Do you know the [MoveMouse](https://sites.google.com/a/windandkite.co.uk/movemouse/home) ?

(It clicks in background invisibly thus your Windows thinks you work and does not fall into sleep.)

Install it and let it run. It is absolutely harmless and does not let your Windows to go to sleep or log out. I know this is a pretty alternative solution but I even recommend to give a try.

Comment: I actually tried a hardware option (mouse jiggler).  I'll try this.